# Client Credential Gran Type Not Support with a Custom B2C Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to generate an access token from our policy but I am getting this error.

```
AADB2C90086: The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported.
```

This is a sample postman request

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token?p=B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInWithAAD HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&resource=https%3A%2F%2F{app_url}&client_secret={client_secret}
```

but it works fine if I don't use our custom policy and just go direct to the B2C tenant

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
... same as above
```

Is there something missing in our custom policy?

Answer (score 5):

B2C does not support the Client Credential Flow.  Additional details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035605/authenticating-as-a-service-with-azure-ad-b2c/47044321#47044321).  And here [Daemons/server-side apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications).

> but it works fine if I don't use our custom policy

That's because you getting a token from Azure AD, not B2C.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   So your saying that even though I am requesting the token from the B2 tenant (no custom policy) the token is actually created by the AD?  When I use the b2c tenant with custom policy it only hits the B2C and hence fails?

Comment: That's correct.  @chookie.  Use a tool like https://jwt.ms to view the token.  The issuer for Azure AD is https://sts.windows.net/[guid].  The issuer for B2C is https://login.microsoftonline.com/[guid]/v2.0