# B2C token Generation. and unique token responses

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to generate a token using service-to-service Client Credentials  Grant type?

We need this so our gateway can call Azure B2C for token generation

Unique attribute in token response:  is there any unique attribute can be configured for each user login session, like user session id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [headless authentication Azure AD b2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072371/headless-authentication-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036907/185123)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported OAuth Grant for Azure B2C. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#daemonsserver-side-apps):

> **Daemons/server-side apps**
>
> Apps that contain long-running processes or that operate without the presence of a user also need a way to access secured resources such as web APIs. These apps can authenticate and get tokens by using the app's identity (rather than a user's delegated identity) and by using the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow.
>
> This flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C. These apps can get tokens only after an interactive user flow has occurred.